# Access Policy or IAM access to create a VM in IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a VM under an IBM Cloud account which does not have access to create VM. So I log back into the admin account to give access but I dont see any way to give access. I tried creating Access Policy but it does not have anything related to VM's. How can I give access to a user to create VM's in IBM Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It is moved to "Assign access to your softlayer account" under Identity & Access under users. 
Once you are in user settings: 
Click on Portal Permissions -> Click on Account tab -> Select "Add Server" checkbox.

This is very non-intuitive I might add.